# Is there any way to transfer programs between laptops?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

My old laptop that I do a lot of work on is starting to die. I have a lot of really important programs on there that would suck to lose. 
Is there a way to perhaps copy these programs and allow them to work on a separate computer? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply just reinstall them on your new machine?  Even if you transfer an application installation directory, most applications, require you to install them in order to work.

Comment: It depends on the program.  Some are "portable" and could be moved, although you might have to copy its entire directory.  Some may have dependencies on system files that would be located somewhere else and may not be part of the default system installation.  If they are Windows laptops, some may have registry entries that would need to be replicated.  If any of the programs are licensed for a specific machine, you might have to jump through some hoops to keep them activated on the new machine.  You might need to replicate shortcuts and menu entries.  (cont'd)

Comment: You might need to recreate working directories.  You might need to ensure that they are included in the backup list on the new machine.  Etc.  There are (or at least were), utilities that would relocate a program for you, doing it one program at a time.  The complexity also varies by OS.  For example, Linux has utilities that will figure out everything that has been changed from the distro as distributed, and allows you to easily move or recreate it.  But short answer: especially for Windows, very little of it could be moved with simple copying.

Comment: For future use, if you migrate the environment into a VM, then you can move the backing VM image between hardware as you have abstracted it. Night not work great for games, but good for many office applications.